# Plot multiple graphs from one JSON-File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, chart.js

**Hey coding-friends!**

I tried to plot multiple graphs from one data-file. The data is in JSON format and looks like this:

```
[{"wert":"100.5","Datetime":"2019.03.29 08:35:04"}]
```

This is the command to display the datasets in JSON format.

```
print str_replace('\\u0000','', json_encode($data));
print str_replace('\\u0000','', json_encode($data1));
```

I can easily adapt the data-file to just display more than one dataset.

That looks like this:

```
[{"wert":"100.5","Datetime":"2019.03.29 08:35:04"}][{"wert1":"10.0","Datetime1":"2019.03.29 08:35:02"}]
```

With one data the plot of the graph works fine. However, I did not figure out how to adapt my JavaScript file to work for more than one dataset.

I get the data from a MySQL database. Every dataset has different names like it is shown.

In the coming code snippet, you can see my javascript file, which is drawing my chart. It is possible to draw two graphs with the same dataset, but not with two different.

I tried to make a second function for the second data called "data1", which is written in the data file as well, but this did not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/html_diplo/Data/data3in1.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      var Datetime = [];
      var wert = [];


      for (var i in data) {
        Datetime.push(data[i].Datetime);
        wert.push(data[i].wert);
      }


      var chartdata = {
        labels: Datetime,
        datasets: [{

          label: 'Leistung [W]',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(000,99,255,0.75)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(000,000,255,0.75)',
          hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
          hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
          data: wert

        }, {

          label: 'Leistung [W]',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(000,99,255,0.75)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(000,000,255,0.75)',
          hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
          hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
          data: wert

        }]


      };


      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var lineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata,

        options: {
          elements: {
            point: {
              radius: 0
            }
          }
        }

      });



    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

    }

  });
});
```

My idea was to plot more than one graph in one chart. The datasets should be in one file.